# Mock React child component in snapshot testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, snapshot

Let's suppose to have a very huge component named 'HugeComponent' and its snapshot test.
This component is used in N other components.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import HugeComponent from './huge-component/HugeComponent';

const FirstComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>My First Component</h1>
      <p>This component renders a huge component</p>
      <HugeComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const SecondComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
       // … 
      <HugeComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

...

const NthComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
       // … 
      <HugeComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

In several snapshot testing tutorials I have noticed that children component are mocked, in order to avoid having large snapshots.

So the related test could be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import MyFirstComponent from './MyFirstComponent';

jest.mock('../huge-component/HugeComponent', () => () => '<HugeComponent/>');

describe('MyFirstComponent', () => {
  it('should renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = create(<MyFirstComponent />);
    expect(tree.toJSON().toMatchSnapshot());
  });
});

// The tests for the other components are similar ...
```

Now let's assume that the HugeComponent implementation changes.
This change breaks HugeComponent snapshot test, but not the others,  where the ui also changes.

So if we do snapshot test to detect component ui changes, why we mock children component, that can potentially change, making the component that renders them different from the starting one?

Edit:
Let's suppose this initial implementation for the HugeComponent:

```
import React from 'react';

const HugeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="first" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="second" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="third" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default HugeComponent;
```

This is the related snapshot for MyFirstComponent (mock not applied)

```
exports[FirstComponent should renders correctly 1] = 
<div
  className="container"
>
  <h1>
    My First Component
  </h1>
  <p>
    This component renders a huge component
  </p>
  <div
    style={
      Object {
        "display": "flex",
        "justifyContent": "center",
      }
    }
  >
    <img
      alt="first"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
    <img
      alt="second"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
    <img
      alt="third"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
  </div>
</div>
;
```

Now let's suppose HugeComponent changes this way:

```
import React from 'react';

const HugeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="first" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="second" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="third" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default HugeComponent;
```

So the related snapshot for MyFirstComponent became:

```
exports[FirstComponent should renders correctly 1] = 
<div
  className="container"
>
  <h1>
    My First Component
  </h1>
  <p>
    This component renders a huge component
  </p>
  <div
    style={
      Object {
        "display": "flex",
        "flexDirection": "column",
        "justifyContent": "center",
      }
    }
  >
    <img
      alt="first"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
    <img
      alt="second"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
    <img
      alt="third"
      src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    />
  </div>
</div>
;
```

When HugeComponent changes, also MyFirstComponent ui changes.

Now if I mock HugeComponent, the test related to MyFirstComponent does not detect this change, even though I have two different components.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: The rendered ui of the N components could not be the same, if HugeComponent implementation changes.

Comment: Did the `jest.mock()` work for `HugeComponent`?

Comment: Yes it works, this is not the problem. 
I try to explain myself better with another example.

Comment: In my opinion and applying the "separation of concerns", if `Huge` changes, `Huge`'s spec should catch that, not the parent components. So I would mock `Huge` in parent component specs and test `Huge` separately.